# Elementary OS Odin installer not showing partitions on Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: macbook, install, disk

I've been running elementary OS alongside Mac OS for a few years now on my Macbook Pro 2016. Now Odin is out, I decided to erase my disk to get rid of Mac OS and go 100% elementary, but I've found some trouble with the new installer. After I click on delete full disk and install, I get a "no enough space" message. Trying to solve it, I decided to go the "custom install" route.

[image]

GParted gives the following error (note that the snapshot here was taken on the live mode just because I forgot to take it while trying to install. Despite the error, Files recognized the disk). I ignored the error so could see my partitions and deleted all of them, creating a new one for Odin.

[image]

But despite of it, the installer does not show the partitions or even the disk

[image]

Note that I've checked that both Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 recognize the disk correctly, so it seems that this could be the new installer's fault.

Edit: it seem it's a [bug](https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/617).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Macbook Pro 2017. Best regards,
Alexander

Comment: https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/617

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be waiting then. I appreciate a lot your time for answering.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25458)